# how to create production build in nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

could you please tell me how to how to create production build in nextjs **with different base path**

I have dynamic base path , getting base path from `env local`.

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/'+process.env.FESTIVALS,
}
```

`.env.local`

```
FESTIVALS = "bonnaroo, lollapalooza, coachella"
```

I want to  create 3 build with base path `bonnaroo` , `lollapalooza`  , `coachella`

I want to run `npm run build`  3 times with basepath `bonnaroo` , `lollapalooza`  , `coachella`

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-sammet-skjyo?file=/next.config.js:0-60

Comment: Provide FESTIVALS environment variable, with cross-env or else. Currently you hard-coded it in env.local

Comment: @EstusFlask but how to run `npm run build` command

Comment: Like `FESTIVAL=... npm run build`. That's how env vars arre meant to be used, they aren't just values in env file. Check cross-env for windows counterpart.

Comment: thanks @EstusFlask . but my question is to run `build` programmatically . first with `bonnaroo `  , second with this `lollapalooza ` ... FESTIVALS may be 100 with `comma seperated` (don't know) it dynamic .I want to run build command same count as festival.

Comment: You said that there's 3 in the question, and you can run 3 commands with && or 'concurrently'. As for 100, make Node script that execs this command with respective env vars.

Comment: << As for 100, make Node script that execs this command with respective env vars. >>> can you please help me in this

Comment: can you please give a small example

Comment: Don't have an opportunity to write full-fledged answer. Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/execa/v/0.6.0 for promise-based command execution and use FESTIVAL in 'env' option.